# how to create json runtime and pass its value to compress method which using gzip

Tags: java, json, compression, jackson

i want to compress the json object runtime. (jackkon + Gzip )

i want to compress the json file that generate run-time using

```
public static String compress(String str) throws IOException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    }
    System.out.println("String length : " + str.length());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    String outStr = out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length());
    return outStr;
 }
```

How can I create json file run time and pass it to **compress** method? for compression because **objectMapper.writeValue** returns void.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue("???", getTransaction());
```

Comment: Compression works on bytes, not strings.  You can't just blindly use `getBytes()` and then blindly convert back to a string.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Where should write value ? in objectMapper.writeValue. I have mark ????